# Android saving current activity

Tags: android

I am developing the Application for cricket. I get problem when I am using back button. My aim is to save the data when user click back button. when user click `back button` or going to another activity the current activity data is not displaying. I used Shared preference to save data. But still I am facing the problem.. can anybody gve some idea. So that i will implement in my application.

I am using `OnResume()` to retrieve the saved data when user press back button.

Comment: You have two activities, first one is calling second one, you want when you press back from second to first , the data which is inputed in the first not changed, right?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan yes u r right.. I am saving data using SharedPreferences in onBackPressed. But some times it showing the saved data. Sometimes it displaying null value

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult` when launching second activity from first activity. In second activity `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("name", value);
    // put as many extra as you want to save
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

}
```

In first activity

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), 1);
```

Then `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
     {
         // Using data to get the extra set in intent i in second activity
         // for example data.getStringExtra("name", ""); and so on
     } 

}
```

The `onActivityResult` is called before `onResume`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity call your second activity like this:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent_To_Second_Activity, 104);
```

In your second activity when you press back use this:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    // Save your data here
}
```

#### Complete working example

#### Main.xml

this is the layout for your first activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="click"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### second.xml

this is the layout for your second activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Java code for your first activity

the class name is `StackActivity`

```
package com.stack.question;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class StackActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    Button bt;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(StackActivity.this, Second.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 104);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Java code for your second activity

```
package com.stack.question;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Second extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

#### Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stack.question"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".StackActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Second"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have codedthe code in my eclipse and it is working.

Comment: How to save Second Activity when user click back button and moved to fist Activity and again open second Activity how to save the data..

Comment: you have to set `onBackPressed` in the first activity and then start the second activity but in this case you have to set the data you want to show in your second activity in the intent, however i don't recomment keep going from first to second to first, this doesn't make any sense and android hasn't build for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

I have Solve this issue this way.

in **activity** class.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("In Destroy()");
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("test",MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefEditor = sharedPref.edit(); 
        //save your data here.      
         prefEditor.commit();
    }
```

**in manifest**.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"  android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Enjoy..

Comment: what is the use of android:launchMode="singleTask" in manifest

Comment: make instance only once when you goto next activity this activity is kill.

Comment: i tried ur code.. my data got saved when i m going to next activity and even i run the application the data from saved preference got retrieved. But when i run my application it shouldn't show the saved data..

Comment: can you elaborate your issue?